# Backbone.js. deep link to section of page

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Im working on an app in Backbone.js. Each page/view containes different sections stacked so the scroll is long. I want to be able to deep link the them by using the router somehow. So the page scrolls to the correct section.

My router looks like this:

```
Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
routes: {
    'chapter-1': 'one',
    'chapter-2': 'two'
},

one: function() {
    new HomeView({el:'#main-view'});
},

two: function() {
    new PurityView({el:'#main-view'});
}
```

});

Now lets say i want to be able to link to one/some-section-id

eg:

```
<section id="some-section-id">
    content
</section>
<section id="another-section-id">
    content
</section>
```

How would i do this?

Comment: Maybe anchor links could do it?

Comment: but since its already a # in the url it won't work i belevie. that woul be www.site.com/#chapter-2#my-section